# How to wire unusual R13-112 rocker switch

Tags: switches, indicator, wire-terminals

Can someone assist me in wiring this switch so the indicator and load can "light up" from 12V battery. By using terminals 1 & 2 I can power on the unit but I have no indicator light. Thanks
[image]

Comment: I would guess that the small terminals control the LED, and it's independent of the large terminals.  That's a neat looking switch, by the way.  Who makes it?  What's the model number?

Comment: SCI R13-112 is part number, I got them in local store, fairly common. So 1/+ goes to +12 and 2/- to -12 ? I think I tried that and short circuited battery :)

Comment: At a guess, connect 1 to +12. Connect 2 both to the high side of the load and through a 1k resistor to +. Connect both the - and the low side to ground, or the - terminal of your battery. If the LED is dim, you can try connecting 2 directly to +, but this may kill the LED.

Comment: Sometimes was dim, I think it was dead before I disassembled the unit if that's possible. Is there a chance for diagram WhatRoughBeast?

Comment: Okay did the wiring like instructed, I got 12V output now and LED in dim mode. Is it broken? I will try 2 <-> + now.

Comment: Hmm same results :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[It's](http://www.sci.com.tw/PRODUCTS/switch/%28R13%29%20ROCKER%20SWITCH/R13-112.htm) made by Shin Chin (新进工业股份有限公司), an established Taiwan-based manufacturer- I recognize that logo. Just an LED and a SPST switch.

[image]

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYGRDC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I have 3P SPST from them too, no mistake on that wiring but I don't understand whats the purpose of 4P SPST

Comment: @iber_zokna It has 4 pins so the LED is independent of the switch.

Comment: I have only dim LED output, is it possible that LED died? About 4 pins, its purpose is that we can have LED on all the time? That's also possible on 3P.

Comment: Yes, or it's possible it was a really crappy LED to begin with (or both!). With 4 pins you could, for example, switch 120VAC with the switch and power the LED from low voltage DC.

Comment: Are resistors must have here? I think that made LED die. I had none on me :)

Comment: You can never tell for sure with this kind of datasheet but looks to me like having no resistor will kill the LED dead (the resistor **is** shown for a neon lamp). Since you took it apart you must have seen there is no resistor, right? And YES there MUST be a resistor somewhere.

Comment: It was in PCB :), for a reason. On 3P rocket switches there is no need for resistors I guess, I will avoid 4P from now on.Thanks Spehro.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Best way to connect the LED Switch]

This is the best way to use this type with the LED only ON when current ia passing, otherwise, and according to the manual connection, you will have the LED always ON.

Comment: Note that this will only work if the switch has an integrated current limiting resistor, and if the voltage source connected is of the same value as the rated voltage.